# SQLClient output parameter returns DBNull

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, output, sqlclient, sqlparameter

Its a ASP.net application in VS2008, connecting to SQL 2005 database.

No errors calling the Stored procedure, db update is successful but the OUTPUT param returns DBnull all the time. Below the vb code:

```
Dim ConnectString As String = "", connect As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
ConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
connect.ConnectionString = ConnectString
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("saveAccess", connect)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Name", "SampleName"))
Dim outparam As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@returnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
outparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(outparam)
connect.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@returnValue").Value Then
    Response.Write("Why does it always returns DBNull")
Else : Response.Write(cmd.Parameters("@returnValue").Value.ToString())
End If
connect.Close()
```

Here is the SQL code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveAccess] 
(@Name NVARCHAR(20), @returnValue INT OUTPUT )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Access ([Name]) VALUES (@Name);

SELECT @returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Not sure what is the silly mistake that I am doing. Any input helps.

Thanks

Comment: you need to close the connection before you can read the output parameter being set in your SPROC. Output parameters are set in the variables once the connection is closed.

Comment: Solution (as said silly myself): missed the @ symbol in front of the returnValue variable. I typed up the code in this posting correctly but I had it without the @ in the SP.

    'code'wrong: SELECT returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;
    
    'code'correct: SELECT @returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SELECT`, try using `SET` to set the value of the output parameter

```
SET @returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin, that helped me put the missing @ symbol in front of the returnValue variable which I was missing. It works now. SET or SELECT works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Solution (as said silly myself): missed the @ symbol in front of the returnValue variable. I typed up the code in this posting correctly but I had it without the @ in the SP.

```
wrong: SELECT returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;

correct: SELECT @returnValue = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Thanks